I'm having an data loss issue using line Graphs in ApexCharts
ApexCharts seems to modify/remove some data, I'm not quite sure if this is a skill issue of mine, or something else.
I'm getting data from an API from my server, the APIs data is intact and seems to appear fine, the format of it is
EDIT: It actually moves all data one day back, so the data from the 5th of april, would be shown as the 4th
[
[
...
{
fileName": "The Dawns Awakening.json",
    "data": {
     ...
      "2024-06-10": 2206772
    }
}
]

I'm using the variable
const JsonExample = [];

to format the data in a usable format for ApexCharts
the part of the code causing issues is below:
async function drawChart(labels, chartData, guildNames, yAxisMax) {
  const JsonExample = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < guildNames.length; i++) {
    const chartDataDict = {};
    chartDataDict.name = guildNames[i]; // Add the name field
    const reversedLabels = labels.slice().reverse();
    const data = [];
    for (let j = 0; j < reversedLabels.length; j++) {
      const date = reversedLabels[j];
      const gexp = chartData[i][chartData[i].length - j];
      data.push([date, gexp]);
    }

    chartDataDict.data = data;
    JsonExample.push(chartDataDict);
  }
  // Print the JSON object
  console.log(JsonExample);


  
  
//now to string
console.log(JSON.stringify(JsonExample));
const jsonData = JSON.stringify(JsonExample);

const seriesData = JSON.parse(jsonData).map(guild => {
  let color

    if (guild.name === "Puffy") {
      color = "#BF40BF"; // Bright Purple
  } else if (guild.name === "Lucid") {
      color = "#FFFF00"; // Yellow
  } else if (guild.name === "Rebel") {
      color = "#0000FF"; // Blue
  } else if (guild.name === "Miscellaneous") {
      color = "#008000"; // Green
  } else if (guild.name === "Sailor Moon") {
      color = "#6699CC"; // Bluegrey
  } else if (guild.name === "The Abyss") {
      color = "#808080"; // Grey
  } else if (guild.name === "The Dawns Awakening") {
      color = "#FF0000"; // Red
  } else if (guild.name === "Leman") {
      color = "#FFA500"; // Orange
  } else if (guild.name === "The Blood Lust"){
      color = "#FF2301";
  } else if (guild.name === "Miscellaneous"){
      color = "#587246";
  } else {
    console.log(guild.name)
    color = "#447b40"; // default color
  }

    return {
        ...guild,
        color: color
    };
});

const options = {
    series: seriesData,
    chart: {
        height: 750,
        width: '100%',
        type: 'line',
        zoom: {
            enabled: true,
            type: 'x'
        },
        foreColor: 'white',
        animations: {
            enabled: false,
            easing: 'easeinout',
            speed: 800,
            animateGradually: {
                enabled: true,
                delay: 50
            },
            dynamicAnimation: {
                enabled: true,
                speed: 350
            },
        }
    },
    colors: seriesData.map(series => series.color),
    dataLabels: {
        enabled: false
    },
    stroke: {
        curve: 'smooth',
        width: 2
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Top Guilds',
        align: 'center',
    },
    xaxis: {
        type: 'datetime'
    },
    yaxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Daily GEXP'
        },
        labels: {
            formatter: (val) => {
                return val.toLocaleString();
            }
        }
    }
};

var chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#chart"), options);
chart.render();
}

I've tried changing the way json is processing the data, this however just caused the guild names, and the data, to mix, causing the last guild to have the first's data and so on.

What is the purpose for converting data back and forth between JS array and JSON?

@Teemu That was the easiest way I found to do what I needed

But but ... const jsonData = JSON.stringify(JsonExample); const seriesData = JSON.parse(jsonData)... just wastes time, it doesn't actually do anything, you can directly map JsonExample, the result is exactly the same.

@Teemu
Oh, I didnt realise

This could possibly be a part of code leftover from a try at fixing the bug

As it happens, I saw the line const gexp = chartData[i][chartData[i].length - j]; which is wrong (when j is 0 it will try to access chartData[i][chartData[i].length] which doesn't exist since the last element is at chartData[i].length -1... also check that the last element accessed by theforcycle ischartData[1]and notchartData[0]). That may be the cause of your shift in xtoycorrespondence. You should replace that line withconst gexp = chartData[i][chartData[i].length - j - 1];`

In general though, you should provide a runnable minimal reproducible example so we can really debug it and find errors by a certain and predictable process.

Thank you @kikon ill try running that, also sorry for the late response.
